# Can I assume asp.net form's ID always being the same?

Tags: asp.net, form-submit

I want to submit a simple asp.net form in jQuery

can I assume

```
$("form[0]").submit()
```

always works, cross browser?

Comment: `$("form[0]")` will try to select all `form` elements on the page that have an element attribute `0`. Aside from that being invalid HTML, *this* is the kind of element your selector would return: `<form id="foo" 0="bar">...</form>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this

```
$("#aspnetForm").submit()
```

Something like above would work cross browser as you said

The code you pasted is cross browser too. It won't work on ANY browser so maybe that counts as cross browser :-) just a joke

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't assume this. `$("form[0]").submit()` will submit the first form on the page. However, you can have more than one form on an ASP.NET page, though only one of these forms can be a server-side form (with `runat="server"` attribute).

If what you want is to submit the server-side form on an ASP.NET page then I think the best way would be to do it in code-behind by registering a script. It's a bit more hassle, but should always work (and when there is no server-side form it will detect it). Something like this:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    if (this.Form != null)
    {
        string js = String.Format("$('#{0}').submit()", this.Form.ClientID);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Submit", js, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dan, that's not what that selector will select. See my comment on the question.

Comment: I didn't bother to check that, I must admit! However, the point is, the code I posted *will* work and will work regardless of what ID you give to the form since it dynamically assigns it based on the actual ID. Hard-coding ID names in web-forms is rarely a good idea (unless you are using ASP.NET 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

These will:

```
$("#aspnetForm").submit()
```

or

```
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
theForm.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that this code will be triggered by an `input` or `button` element within the ASP.NET form, or if you can select a known `input` or `button` element within the ASP.NET form, you can use `input.form.submit();`.

**Usage examples**

> this.form.submit();

or

> $("#some_input_or_button").get(0).form.submit();

Although reading the `input.form`/`button.form` property does not use jQuery, it is at least as cross-browser since [jQuery itself does this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js#L764).

**Benefit:** This method allows you to avoid dependence on the form ID generated by ASP.NET's internals without having to add any extra wiring server-side.